# catch exceptionorg.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to query hive table from spark scala code and getting below error:

```
catch exceptionorg.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `databaseName`.`register`; line 1 pos 35;
'Distinct
+- 'Project ['computer_name]
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation `databaseName`.`register`

job failed
```

Here is the code, to read the data from Hive.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
val hc = spark.sqlContext
val dbName = "databaseName"
val tblName = "register"
    val HostDF = hc.sql(s"""select distinct computer_name from ${dbName}.${tblName} """)
```

If I ran through spark-shell, I don't see any issue and I am getting the data.

If I am using same code through spark scala code(I mean running jar in cluster mode), I am getting above mentioned error.

Could any one tell me what I am doing wrong in code Vs spark-shell?

Thanks,
Bab

Answer (score 0):

Try troubleshooting, by looking into env or db/tables and compare

print conf values

```
sqlContext.getAllConfs.foreach(println _)
```

or print dbnames and tables names

```
sqlContext.tableNames().foreach(println _)
```

Comment: I found the issue. I did not enable hive in spark session. Thank you for your response.